# PAM's passwd retry prompt fail

Tags: linux, pam, passwd

I am trying to use PAM to stop password reuse. Adding 'remember=24' to pam_unix stores the old passwords hashed with MD5 which I find unnerving. I was recommended 'pam_pwhistory' instead. Here is the password section of my /etc/pam.d/system-auth file that /etc/pam.d/passwd includes

```
password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so retry=3 try_first_pass
password    requisite     pam_pwhistory.so remember=24 retry=3 use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 rounds=5000 shadow use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so
```

When I try to change my password, if I fail the password reuse test, I don't get to retry. Instead a "Password:" prompt appears

```
$ passwd
(current) Unix password: <current password>
New password: <old password>
Retype new password: <old_password>
Password has already been used. Choose another.
Password: <current password>
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

I have a similar same issue if I fail the pam_cracklib test more than the retry #. Except that my current password works with the prompt

```
$ passwd
(current) Unix password: <correct password>
New password: <too simple password>
BAD PASSWORD: it too simple
New password: <too simple password>
BAD PASSWORD: it too simple
New password: <too simple password>
BAD PASSWORD: it too simple
Password: <current password>
passwd: Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service
```

If I set retry=1 for pam_pwhistory, then the current password works for the prompt.

```
$ passwd
(current) Unix password: <current password>
New password: <old password>
Retype new password: <old_password>
Password has already been used. Choose another.
Password: <current password>
passwd: Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service
```

The inablility to retry if you use an old password and this strange 'Password: ' are the only problem. Old passwords are stored in /etc/security/opasswd using their original hash function.
It looks like

1. pam_pwhistory can't retry because it's in the middle of the stack?
2. A failure in pam_pwhistory doesn't cause pam_unix to fail, it instead 
   prompts user?

I am on a CentOS 6.3